# Eclipse C/C++ problems + Cygwin (complain on everything)

Tags: c++, cygwin, syntax-error, eclipse-cdt

So im running Eclipse C/C++ with Cygwin.

I can run and compile smoothly:

My test.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "This is a demonstration! \n";
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And I can successfully build with this makefile:

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project HelloWorld ****

make all 
Building file: ../test.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"test.d" -MT"test.d" -o "test.o"             "../test.cpp"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\David\cworkspace\HelloWorld\Release
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/David/cworkspace/HelloWorld/Release
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Finished building: ../test.cpp

Building target: HelloWorld
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "HelloWorld"  ./test.o   
Finished building target: HelloWorld


**** Build Finished ****
```

After that I get HelloWorld.exe which I can run fine.

My problem is, eclipse complain on everything! It says ive got lots of errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Function 'sleep' could not be resolved  test.cpp    /HelloWorld line 6  Semantic Error
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved test.cpp    /HelloWorld line 5  Semantic Error
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved  test.cpp    /HelloWorld line 2  Semantic Error
```

I mean, this is obviously not the case if you read the code.

I have tried:

```
Index->Update with modified files

Index->Freshen all files

Index->Create parser log file
```

which was the tips i've found on other websites.

How should I tackle this problem?!

Comment: Well, as for `sleep` it is right - you should include `<unistd.h>` for it.

Comment: Ye, that might be true. But still. I still get the other errors which I shouldnt get. But thanks for the info.

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse knows in which directory to look for the headers? With Cygwin it's `/usr/include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the test.cpp a dos or unix file? Hidden characters such line endings could be the issue.

Try `unix2dos test.cpp`